# Can Google Apps Script process GET query string and post to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, query-string

I'm trying to learn Apps Script. I wonder if it is possible for a script to receive `GET` requests and then enter the query string values to a Google Sheet.

For example, if we execute this command:

```
$ curl https://script.google.com/d/xxx-xxx-xxx/?header1=value1&header2=value2&headerN=valueN
```

Then we could expect a Google Sheet to be populated with column headers `header1`, `header2`, up to `headerN` along with rows of `values` from the query string.

Would this be possible? A simple sample Apps Script will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes :) This is possible. Please refer to the [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) > **e.queryString**.

I suppose, that should do the trick but please feel to come back here again in case you require further clarifications.